# asp.net mvc vs asp.net webform

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have to choose between learning to technologies in asp.net (mvc or webforms).

which one is better and also having a doubt of whether is learning webforms is mandatory or else help to understand better in learning mvc.

Comment: They are both old technologies. Do you want to learn them out of interest or do you  want to learn them do get a job/do professional projects with them? I would suggest to switch to [asp.net core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/introduction-to-aspnet-core?view=aspnetcore-7.0), since it is the successor of the two.

Comment: I want to learn these to get a job.

Comment: Then I would suggest to learn asp.net core.

Comment: If you using free materials, then perhaps dabbling in webforms is a great learning experience. However, if you paying for any of your courses or material? Then the reason you PAY for courses etc. is to learn new valuable market skills. WebForms can be a valuable skill since so many legacy web sites are being upgraded. but you would NEVER pay for material and course(s) to learn webforms, since they are really fantastic, and super easy to use + learn. So, if you paying, then of course learn .net core stuff, blazer and all the current new tools being used. So for jobs? No, do lean new things.